# Openlayers 2 and Google Streets

Tags: google-maps, openlayers-2

I don't know why since yesterday Google Streets baselayer is not displayed if Google Hybrid is not selected first. I thought it was my fault but the same happens with the example: http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/google.html
Anybody knows?. Regards, Ramiro.

Comment: The workarround I found  is to programmatically select hybrid and then switch to streets. But i don't like it.